# Make iOS bar button item for iOS 6 to look like iOS 7 UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I want to use a UILabel with the text set as @"+" to look like the UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd in iOS 7. So far I have...

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
[lbl setText:@"+"];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]];
[lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:lbl];
```

... but the problem is the + isn't vertically central on the nav bar. I've tried changing the frame of the label but the + always appears in the same place, slightly too low.

Any ideas?

Comment: A comparison screenshot would be immensely helpful

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is the + isn't vertically central on the nav bar

Consider using an image instead of a string. With an image, you'll have more control over exactly how the button is drawn.

Comment: I can't do that because its part of a framework in which I want users to be able to change the color. Its easy to change a font color but less so for an image